# HTML Drag And Drop On Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, mobile-devices

When you add drag and drop to a web page using JavaScript, such as jQuery UI draggable and droppable, how do you get this to work when viewed via a browser on a mobile device - where the touch-screen actions for dragging are intercepted by the phone for scrolling around the page etc?

All solutions welcome... my initial thoughts are:

1. Have a button for mobile devices that "lifts" the item to be dragged and then get them to click the zone they want to drop the item on.
2. Write an app that does this for mobile devices rather then try and get the web page to work on them!
3. Your suggestions and comments please.

Comment: Which devices are you targeting?

Comment: @Marko - all of them. It isn't The Web if I exclude anyone.

Comment: If you don't want jQuery at all, take a look at this
https://github.com/capriza/mobile-touch

Comment: Asked 10 years, 5 months ago
Active 1 year, 2 months ago
Viewed 131k times

Comment: Any ide why in mobile the page is not scrolling if you want to drag the element all the way to the bottom in mobile.  It works fine in desktop though

Comment: It would be really nice if a SINGLE ONE of the many answers below actually discussed how to do it rather than advertise a third party library. And echoing @JasonFB, amazing that in - now - 2022, there is still no clear answer.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

jQuery UI Touch Punch just solves it all.

It's a Touch Event Support for jQuery UI. Basically, it just wires touch event back to jQuery UI.
Tested on iPad, iPhone, Android and other touch-enabled mobile devices.
I used jQuery UI sortable and it works like a charm.

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

Comment: Doesn't work on the stock Android 4.0 browser. It does work on mobile Chrome though.

Comment: do we have long press first before drag? because when we used full width in element that drag able then we want to scroll to bottom it automatically drags the element

Comment: make sure to make this your last <script> declaration in the head of your html file, especially jquery-ui, or it won't work

Comment: @vichsu Thanks so much for this answer, which just perfectly solved my problem.

Comment: really not working in android 4.0 .. or is there any work around ?

Comment: What about people who don't want to include jQuery UI since it is a huge library just to handle touch drag and drop? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Not the best solution: if the element to drag takes the whole viewport, using jQuery UI Touch Punch prevents the document to be scrolled. Can be even a problem with element you want to be only draggable horizontally with a container hiding overflow, as a draggable carousel. In this case, the carousel prevents user to scroll the document up and down. I prefer jQuery Touch (github.com/ajlkn/jquery.touch) which makes draggable possibly touch only on mobile (mouse gesture can be filtered) and does not prevent touch events to propagate (thus, document to be scrolled).

Comment: touchpunch.furf.com is 404, the solution is missing

Comment: There's a working and refined fork: https://github.com/RWAP/jquery-ui-touch-punch

Answer (score 31):

There is a polyfill for translating touch events to drag-and-drop, such that HTML5 Drag And Drop is utilizable on mobile.

The polyfill was introduced by Bernardo Castilho on [this post](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1091766/Add-support-for-standard-HTML-Drag-and-Drop-operat).

Here's a [demo](http://bernardo-castilho.github.io/DragDropTouch/demo/) from that post.

The post also presents several considerations of the polyfill design.

Comment: no working on mobile devices

Answer (score 9):

I needed to create a drag and drop + rotation that works on desktop, mobile, tablet including windows phone. The last one made it more complicated (mspointer vs. touch events).

The solution came from The great [Greensock library](http://www.greensock.com/draggable/)

It took some jumping through hoops to make the same object draggable and rotatable but it works perfectly

Comment: License type? Free? I checked out the site, but it seems like they are selling the library.

Comment: It's been 6 years since I answered this. I am not sure if they changed their license type. It used to be free back in 2014...

Comment: IDK how I overlooked this, but https://greensock.com/licensing/

Comment: Basically, its free provided that your product is free (with the exception that they permit one time charges), other wise, you have to get a business license with them.

Answer (score 8):

The beta version of [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) has drag and drop support.

You can refer to their [DnD Example](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/dragdrop/). This only works on webkit browsers by the way.

Retrofitting that logic into a web page is probably going to be difficult. As I understand it they disable all browser panning and implement panning events entirely in javascript, allowing correct interpretation of drag and drop.

**Update:** the original example link is dead, but I found this alternative:
https://github.com/kostysh/Drag-Drop-example-for-Sencha-Touch

Comment: This is very interesting, so I will download it and have a play - tested on Android and it mostly works, so just need to look at the details - thanks!

Comment: Okay, I probably won't use that library in particular (what with it being over 200k when minified), but I can use the concepts contained within it to get the kind of idea. The general idea is that you make your page cannot be interpreted as greater than the size of the screen, which fools the mobile browser into not intercepting the swipes / drags!

Comment: Sohnee, we're adding a builder for Touch 1.0 that strips out unused parts of the library, this will get the footprint down substantially. Also, gzipped, the full library is 50-80k.

Answer (score 6):

The [Sortable JS library](https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/) is compatible with touch screens and does not require jQuery.

The library size is 43KB.

The official website states in a video that this library is running faster than JQuery UI Sortable.

Comment: Look like this one is working even though it looks more like CDK Drag Drop library of Angular 10 though.

Comment: Tested on Firefox Nightly 92.0a1 on Android 9: seems to work, but long touch triggers scrolling and dragging at the same time, possibly because long touch is normally used for text selection

Comment: IMO this answer is underappreciated. Library works for me on windows touchscreen (which many answers here did not), is opensource/mit, and comes with great examples and packages for most popular web frameworks. (react-sortablejs was exactly what i needed)

Comment: @Zoup, this is a very nice and useful advice.

Answer (score 5):

You might as well give a try to [**Tim Ruffle's drag-n-drop polyfill**](http://timruffles.github.io/mobile-drag-drop/demo/), certainly similar to *Bernardo Castilho*'s one (see @remdevtec answer).

Simply do `npm install mobile-drag-drop --save` (other installation methods available, e.g. with bower)

Then, any element interface relying on touch detection should work on mobile (e.g. dragging only an element, instead of scrolling + dragging at the same time).

Comment: Have tried by simulating the web app behavior on mobile device with [drag-n-drop polyfill](https://www.timr.co/mobile-drag-drop/demo/) but it does not work at all.

Comment: It works great, the source is here: https://github.com/timruffles/mobile-drag-drop

Answer (score 1):

Jquery Touch Punch is great but what it also does is disable all the controls on the draggable div so to prevent this you have to alter the lines... (at the time of writing - line 75)

change

```
if (touchHandled || !self._mouseCapture(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0])){
```

to read

```
if (touchHandled || !self._mouseCapture(event.originalEvent.changedTouches[0]) || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'textarea'
        || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'input' || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'button' || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'li'
        || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'a'
        || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'select' || event.originalEvent.target.localName === 'img') {
```

add as many ors as you want for each of the elements you want to 'unlock'

Hope that helps someone

Comment: It most definetly helped me, thank you. I was creating a sortable checklist and the tick box was not clicking as the div created by touch-punch was covering the checkbox. This solved it and it worked. thanks....

Answer (score 1):

here is my solution:

```
$(el).on('touchstart', function(e) {
    var link = $(e.target.parentNode).closest('a')  
    if(link.length > 0) {
        window.location.href = link.attr('href');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For vue 3, there is https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next

For vue 2, it's https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

The latter you can use like this:

```
<draggable v-model="myArray" group="people" @start="drag=true" @end="drag=false">
   <div v-for="element in myArray" :key="element.id">{{element.name}}</div>
</draggable>
```

These are based on sortable.js