# How do you use mouse events in Phonegap/Cordova?

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I've been trying to use mousemove,mousedown,mouseup but they wont work, is there a different way that you have to do this in Phonegap/Cordova? Im doing a android application. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is a different way. First you have to understand, those events don't work in android application. Instead you should use these events:

```
mousedown -> touchstart
mousemove -> touchmove
mouseup   -> touchend
```

But if you still need mouse events you can replicate them like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6175148/1848600