# Ionic Event-LIsteners on-hold/on-tab Parent/Child Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

In an cordova/ionic app there is a parent-div on which on-hold-listener is attached and a child-div which subscribed for on-tab events like so:

```
<div on-hold="doSomething()">
   <div on-tap="doSomething2()">...</div>
</div>
```

From time to time it works but there have been situations in what on-tab was executed instead of on-hold when pressing time was bigger than 500ms.

Might this be done in a better way? Please take into consideration that child-div fills out parent completely and it should remain so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want the doSomething() to only be in your parent div you can get the target element in your function and check if it is the parent that has been on-hold.

Comment: Yes, this is true but I want to prevent on-tap of child to be fired instead when is going to be a hold-event. doSomething is always done by parent as is doSomething2 done by child so checking for target would be in vain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with stopPropagation I came up with following answer that needs setTimeout to check for mouse/cursor is being holded.

When just clicking on the child-div(red) doSomething2 is alerted whereas holding onto child-div alerts doSomething of parent instead:

```js
var holding = false;
var secondFunctionCall = false;

document.getElementById("c1").addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
 
  holding = true;

  setTimeout(function(){
    if(holding){
      secondFunctionCall = false;
      alert("calling doSomething()");
    }
  },500);

}, false);

document.getElementById("c2").addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {

  holding = true;
  secondFunctionCall = true;

}, false);

document.getElementById("c2").addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {

  holding = false;

  if(secondFunctionCall){
    alert("calling doSomething2()");
  }

}, false);
```

```css
#c2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#c1 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
  </div>
</div>
```

When transfering this code into a cordova-app mouse-event types have to be replaced by touch-event types as it is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892263/how-do-you-use-mouse-events-in-phonegap-cordova).

Answer (score 1):

When you have a div parent of another div the events are propagated.
You can try by yourself here:

```css
.c2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.c1 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1" onclick="alert('squareParent');">
  <div class="c2" onclick="alert('squareChild');">
  </div>
</div>
```

To avoid this you need to stop the propagation:

```js
document.getElementById("c1").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert("c1");
}, false);

document.getElementById("c2").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert("c2");
  e.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

```css
#c2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#c1 {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="c1">
  <div id="c2">
  </div>
</div>
```

You could check more about javascript bubble if you want more information.

Comment: Have a try at: element.bind('click', function (event) { ....your function... event.stopPropagation(); }); in your controller

Comment: I had a little try with stopPropagation unfortunately it didn't work out as planned, so I modified your answer a little bit, can I attach it to your answer for I can grant your answer to be right and give you points ;)

Comment: Yes sure, as long as it worked for you then it might work for other people.

Comment: Sorry Bertrand I had to make another answer for it had been removed.