# angular directive clear field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I am trying to implement an angular directive in my ionic app to add an 'X' button to a text field that when clicked clears the text. The code is based on this repo: https://github.com/amageed/angular-resetfield

I am unable to get the reset anonymous function called... I.e. the resetting log statement does not show, but the linking statement does:

```
.directive('resetField', ['$compile', '$timeout', function($compile, $timeout) {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {},
        link: function(scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {

            console.log('linking ');

            // limit to input element of specific types
            var inputTypes = /text|search|tel|url|email|password/i;
            if (el[0].nodeName === "INPUT") {
                if (!inputTypes.test(attrs.type)) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid input type for resetField: " + attrs.type);
                }
            } else if (el[0].nodeName !== "TEXTAREA") {
                throw new Error("resetField is limited to input and textarea elements");
            }

            // compiled reset icon template
            var template = $compile('<i ng-show="enabled" ng-click="reset();" class="icon ion-close reset-field-icon"></i>')(scope);
            el.addClass("reset-field");
            el.after(template);

            scope.reset = function() {
                console.log('resetting');
                ctrl.$setViewValue(null);
                ctrl.$render();
                $timeout(function() {
                    el[0].focus();
                }, 0, false);
                scope.enabled = false;
            };

            el.bind('input', function() {
                scope.enabled = !ctrl.$isEmpty(el.val());
            })
            .bind('focus', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.enabled = !ctrl.$isEmpty(el.val());
                    scope.$apply();
                }, 0, false);
            })
            .bind('blur', function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    scope.enabled = false;
                    scope.$apply();
                }, 0, false);
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here is the usage in HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" autocorrect="off" reset-field>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a IIFE instead of a $scope function that needs to be called?

Answer (score 2):

> The problem arises because the `blur` event (always) fires before the `click` event.

When the `blur` event fires, `$scope.enabled` becomes `false`, so the button immediately disappears, before the `click` event can fire.

> What you need is an event that (always) fires before `blur`, namely `ng-mousedown`

---

All you need to do is change:

`ng-click="reset();">`

to

`ng-mousedown="reset();">`

and it works.

---

As the events now always fire in the correct order, there is nothing else to change in your code.

The `X` icon could be anywhere on the page, and it would still work.

If you wish to place it over the input box, just add:

```
style="position:relative;right:15px;top:1px;cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;"
```

to the `<i>` tag.

---

Please find a [**working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Llcwhq?p=preview) of your `angular directive clear field` code.

---

To learn about the difference between the `click` and `mousedown` events, [please read this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html).

And to test the order of DOM events, please [check this pen](http://codepen.io/mudassir0909/pen/eIHqB).

### ----------

**UPDATE**: How to handle the case of a Cordova environment

I (belatedly) realised the Cordova environment did not handle events the same way the browser does.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892263/how-do-you-use-mouse-events-in-phonegap-cordova) gives an equivalence table of the `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `mousemove` events.

As `touchstart` is equivalent to `mousedown`, `ng-mousedown="reset();">` should be replaced in this solution by `ng-touchstart="reset();">`;

`ng-touchstart` does not exist out-of-the-box, but according to this [github repo](https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchstart/blob/master/ngTouchstart.js), you could create the directive like so:

```
.directive("ngTouchstart", function () {
  return {
    controller: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      $element.bind('touchstart', onTouchStart);

      function onTouchStart(event) {
        var method = '$scope.' + $element.attr('ng-touchstart');
        $scope.$apply(function () {
          eval(method);
        });
      };
    }
  };
});
```

As of yet, I have not come round to testing this solution in a Cordova environment, but I will...

### ----------

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION**: after I posted the answer above, you made the following comments:

"*this did not work. could it have something to do with the fact that I am using the ng-model in a query? Also, I tried putting the reset code into bind, the clear does work, but the filter isn't reapplied.*"

and

"yes, it works in the plunker but not in the ios sim."

---

ANSWER TO YOUR COMMENTS

My answer is based solely upon the directive code and the HTML code you provided.

Your question was: "*I am unable to get the reset anonymous function called... I.e. the resetting log statement does not show*"

I took the best of care to answer your question as precisely as possible, explain the issue and provide a working plunker to prove the point: the reset function cannot be called because the focus event takes precedence; when you replace `ng-click` by `ng-mousedown` it works, as thoroughly detailed by provided sources and shown in the plunker I provided.

The question in your original post has then been answered, the issue was explained, and a working solution provided.

---

You mention ios. I just tested my plunker in an iPad: it works perfectly. If there is a specific device with which the solution I provided is not compatible, I will be happy to try and find a workaround.

Now you seem to have additional, unrelated issues, that could not be foreseen by the code provided in the original post.

If it is the case, please ask another question; you could copy/paste the code in my plunker, provide a new plunker and as many details as possible regarding your current issues.

Again, I will be happy to try to answer to the best of my abilities...

Comment: this did not work. could it have something to do with the fact that I am using the ng-model in a query? Also, I tried putting the reset code into bind, the clear does work, but the filter isn't reapplied.

Comment: Did you try the plunker?

Comment: yes, it works in the plunker but not in the ios sim.

Comment: @thebiglebowski11 my answer to you current issues would not fit as a comment: please check update at the end of my answer

Comment: i know i already selected your answer... but when testing on a device this still does not work properly. It works as expected in a browser, but not in an app.

Comment: for what device did it fail?

Comment: ios device, simulator and physical device

Comment: It works on iPad 2 with ios 8.1.2, which is the only one I have available; when you say it does not work in your simulator: what events are detected, in which order?

Comment: are you running it from a browser?

Comment: Ok. Try to replace mousedown with touchstart (events in Cordova are different to browser events) and tell me what you get. I am posting from my phone, so I cannot do the testing right now

Comment: You will need a ng-touchstart directive to re place ng - mousedown in cordova: https://github.com/marktopper/ngTouchstart/blob/master/ngTouchstart.js

Comment: @thebiglebowski11 I updated my answer for the Cordova environment. Hope it works as it should, this time.

Answer (score 0):

I got your code working,
[check this JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/musobirete/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

I changed:

```
class="icon ion-close reset-field-icon"
```

to font awesomes:

```
class="fa fa-times-circle"
```

And it worked.

There is some other code that you left out in your question as well. Take a look and find out what you missed.

Comment: What does not work? When you type in the input you are getting the X. And when you clicking the X it clears the input and prints resetting in the console. That works at least on my computer.