# JQuery Moblie (or alternative) Drag & Drop to drop zones

Tags: html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

Hoping someone can help me find a good mobile web solution for handling the UI for something along the lines of picking horses in a race to "win", "place" or "show".

I'd like users to be presented with a relatively short list of, say, horse names w/small picture and then be able to drag them into one of 3 drop zones (each of which accepts one and only one name). Server should then be told the ID of the horse in each drop zone. Ideally names would animate into drop zone if dropped near it, but snapping ok too.

Rails back-end but that shouldn't really matter.

Needs to work with mobile screens (touch drag & drop)...and ideally standard browsers as well,. JQuery UI and JQuery Mobile get close with their "sortable" demos. But that appears to be directed for re-organizing a list. I need help creating "drop zones" and submitting contents of each back to server.

Ideas? Perhaps someone has seen some sample code along these lines?

Answer (score 0):

Similar stack overflow question :
I'd check out this stack overflow question if you haven't already. [Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices)

1st Alternative:
[There is this JQuery UI Drag drop and sortables blog by simon battersby](http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-ui/)

2nd Alternative:
[There is JQUery mobile drag and drop by Steve Fenton](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Jquery-Mobile-Drag-And-Drop/)

3rd Alternative:
I'd try [sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/).  It might be more than what you are looking for, but it is a great mobile js framework that should have what you need.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?102154-Drag-drop-sort-in-Touch&p=659116#post659116