# Sortable list view in jQuery Mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-sortable

Is there a functionality in jQuery Mobile for making listviews sortable?

By sortable, I mean possibility for the user to reorder elements in the list by dragging, like on the iPhone.

Applying jQuery UI sortable effect on the listview makes it sortable on desktop browser, but not on mobile.

*Update:*
I was trying [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices) solutions. Touch Punch makes drag'n'drop functionality to work, but only when the list is not longer then the device screen. If some items are out of the screen (you need to scroll down to see them), then functionality gets broken: when you're dragging an item, it gets the wrong position.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I have the exact same problem as mentioned in your update

Comment: It was almost a year ago, I don't remember what I did exactly. I think I just added a buttons to move elements up/down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, thats almost exactly what I've resorted to.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Sorry that I couldn't give you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to use jquery ui sortable along with jquery mobile list view, see the code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
        <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

and make sure you add the jqueryui library to the

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then call the sortable function:

```
<script>
        $(function() {
                $( ".sortable" ).sortable();
                $( ".sortable" ).disableSelection();
        });
</script>
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: this doesn't work in IE10 or IE11, however it does work in compatibility mode.

Comment: This works... Until you see one day all the weird errors of mixing JQuery UI and JQuery Mobile. I strongly DO NOT recommend that!