# YUI version 2.x, and drag and drop with touch events

Tags: javascript, ipad, touch, yui

We've got some pretty complex code that's utilising the drag and drop functionality provided by the YUI JavaScript library. We've recently ported the app to be more iPad / mobile friendly, however we're having some problems with the touch events, and the drag and drop functionality offered in YUI. More specifically we're using `YUI 2.7.0` which doesn't explicitly offer touch support for the drag and drop library.

After doing some research I discovered that `YUI 3.x` *does* offer support, however we're reluctant to upgrade due to the significant number of changes. We also feel that if we were to upgrade we would probably consider porting all of the YUI stuff to jQuery.

I've tried using [the fix detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362527/259656) to register the touch events, and it seems to work to some extend. The drag and drop now works, and it's all lovely at first glance; however with this quick fix in place the tap-to-zoom no longer works, and the scrolling is difficult, if not impossible most of the time.

### Are there any hotfixes for YUI 2.x drag and drop with touch events?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I was unable to directly resolve this problem, I was able to adopt the approach outlined in "[Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices)". By registering the same controls, that are draggable, to the custom touch event handler, everything seemed to work as expected.