# Drag & Drop on IPad Web App - while remaining Scroll functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-ui, web-applications

I am using Jquery UI Drag and Drop ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable ) together with https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch
to map touch events over to mouse events. The whole drag and drop thing works fine so far.

The problem I have now is that I have a long list of draggable elements and I need to be able to scroll through the list on IPad as well... When I made the list elements draggable this won't work anymore.

I tried using the jqueryui provided constraints like `distance` and `delay` 
- but even then the scroll event seems to be totally disabled / overlayed with the drag event.

I probably need to write a custom function like "only if move to left at least 50 px make it draggable" or something.

Has anybody ever encountered a similar problem and is willing to share som thoughts about it?
Are any other mobile web frameworks like Sencha or JQmobile equipped with such functionality?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by switching from https://github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch
to the code in this solution: [Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices).

In the end all I needed to adjust was to remove the `event.preventDefault();` to re-enable scolling.

**Edit**

Basically I used the code from the second answer I linked - with some adjustments.
Here is the JS fiddle of my solution, hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/LQuyr/8/

Comment: I found that if you wrap the event.preventDefault() in an if statement that only causes it to fire on mousemove then it prevents any issues with the blocking of other event types.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle example of your working javascript please? It is not clear what modifications need to be done.

Comment: added a fiddle of my solution

Comment: I opened the jsfiddle in an iPhone, and zoomed in so the "Element 1" divs are off the top and bottom of the page, to test scrolling. I find that touching an element and scrolling doesn't scroll - it moves the element. I may have misunderstood, but I thought the idea was to allow scrolling when touching draggable divs, and only drag if the divs are touched for a period of time.

Comment: Additionally you might want to prevent the ui-sortable from scrolling while dragging, e.g. by adding a css class when dragging.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your design of course, but you could try using handles.

Here is jQuery UI's documentation example :

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p class="ui-widget-header">drag with handle</p>
</div>
<div id="draggable2" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>drag from content</p>
    <p class="ui-widget-header">not drag with handle</p>
</div>

$("#draggable").draggable({handle:"p"});
$("#draggable2").draggable({cancel:"p.ui-widget-header"});
```

Or at least the option cancel could give you a start.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dn9DX/

Comment: thanks for your answer... i tried to make just a <span> inside the <li> element draggable, but that is not the desired UI design. the whole <li> should be draggable and scrollable....

Comment: Is your ul tag using 100% of the width of your iPad ? How about using something similar to what they did on the .slider() demo page here : http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll This simple scrollbar example could be a neat workaround. Another workaround is to add a button to make the whole thing draggable or not, but again it depends on what your app is supposed to do...

Comment: nah, it only like 20% of the landcscape view. there are 2 scrollable lists with drag elements and 60% width canvas drop zone more or less