# How to scroll long jquerymobile listview with draggable li elements inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building a jquerymobile (1.3.1)  application and using Jquery-UI draggable,
and [touch-punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) to enable touch events on mobile devices.

I have a long listview, each element in listview can be dragged left or right 10 px on x axis only.

The problem is that I can't scroll that listview down, cause dragging is start.

I have tried to play with distance and scrollSensitivity properties of draggable but with no success.

In addition I found [this SO solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983805/drag-drop-on-ipad-web-app-while-remaining-scroll-functionality), but it is not helped me also.

Basically what I need (at least I think so) is to know if delta Y > delta X, on the beginning (let say 100 ms after start) and cancel draggable if yes.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
var attachDrag = function(selector){
//alert("function attache drag")
$(selector).draggable({ 
    axis: "x", 
    revert: true, 
    revertDuration: 50,
    //scroll: true,
    //distance: 20,
    //scrollSensitivity: 10, 
    //containment:  [-20, 0, 20, 0],
    containment:  "document",
    //iframeFix: true,
    start: function(event, ui) {
        start = ui.position.left;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var tagid = $(event.target).attr("data-tagid");
        sessionVars.setTagId(tagid);
        stop = ui.position.left;


        if (start < stop){//move right - rename 
            $('#popupTag').popup("open");
        }else{ //move left - delete
            $('#popupTag').popup("open");
        }

    }       
}); 
}
```

Comment: if your purpose of using draggable is to delete or rename the target `li`, its much easier using `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events. Not to mention, you dont need to load extra libraries for this purpose.

Comment: test this on your mobile device http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Frnhd/

Comment: @Omar Thank for your suggestion and the fidlle, I'm familiar with that alternative, the effect that I want to achieve is like email list on GMAIL application for android,
In other words I want the LI element will follow my finger when I move it, I started with swipe event but was unable to figure out that issue...