# Making QapTcha function on touch screens

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch, captcha

I am trying to add a [Qaptcha](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/qaptcha/) feature to my comment form and it works fine but does not function on touch screens.

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices) that all I need to do to solve this issue is to add:

```
function touchHandler(event)
{
 var touches = event.changedTouches,
    first = touches[0],
    type = "";

     switch(event.type)
{
    case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
    case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;        
    case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
    default: return;
}
var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
                          first.screenX, first.screenY,
                          first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
                          false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);

first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
event.preventDefault();
}

function init()
{
   document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
   document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);    
}
```

And just call the init() function in my document.ready.

This is part is my document.ready:

```
$outer.= '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){if(jQuery("p:has(\'textarea\')").length>0) jQuery("p:has(\'textarea\')").before(\'<div class="QapTcha"></div>\'); else jQuery("#comment").before(\'<div class="QapTcha"></div>\');jQuery(\'.QapTcha\').QapTcha({disabledSubmit:true,autoRevert:true});});</script>'."\n";
```

I tried this but could not make it function. **Maybe I am not calling it correctly in document.ready**? Can you kindly assist?