# Drag and drop errors with Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, ipad, drag-and-drop

I am a question regarding the ipad app drag and drop error.

I am using Jquery UI and http://touchpunch.furf.com/ touch punch.

I can only seem to drag and drop on the first item then I got bunch of errors in my console

saying

```
event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future.

TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this._mouseDownEvent.pageX') on my jquery ui file.
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same issue.  Unintentionally, the `jquery.ui.touch-punch.js` file I had downloaded was the old version 0.1.0 from 2010.
As soon as I re-downloaded the file (this time the proper v0.2.2) it worked great.

Turns out I had accidentally downloaded it from [this fork](https://github.com/yeco/jquery-ui-touch-punch) instead of the [official source](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) and I'm guessing the same thing happened to you.

I had stumbled onto that fork when I clicked the link provided by the top answer on this SO post: [Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices)

Hope this helps you too!