# how to make jquery draggable works on touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

i have a project thats already work on desktops and i need it to be supported on touch devices

currently i'm using jQuery ui .draggable()

```
object.droppable( {
  accept: '#draggable div',
  hoverClass: 'hovered',
  drop: handleDrop,
} );
```

is there any way that i can make touch events treated as draggable so i'll not needed to edit my code a lot ??

i've tried this touch punch http://touchpunch.furf.com
but it doesn't work for some reason even the demo on the link doesn't work on my android as well

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices)

Comment: @Rob thank you it really worked.. i used the code Yckart post