# How make angular js draggable elements work on tablet (on touch)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on Angular JS draggable directive. My code is similar to this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IdAqeqYFQVCaWF39OPQ1?p=preview)

Both my code and this plunker work perfectly on windows when operating with mouse. But on any tab where touch is involved it is not working at all. what might be the reason behind this? any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Hey did you manage to make it work? If so an example would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A directive was implemented to control touch events, it is ngTouch. You can find more information here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch

I additionally I think this post can be helpful:

[Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices)