# Bind dragstart and drop events to touch events

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, touch

Referring to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362527/3034646

How would I bind the touch events such that they will perform the dragstart and drop events?
I've tried binding dragstart to touchdown and drop to touchup but this results in dragstart not picking up on dataTransfer.get/setData.

Is it possible to map the touch events to replicate dragstart and drop?

Comment: any ideas anyone?

Comment: Possible solution at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53530511/imitating-drag-and-drop-events-with-touch-events-for-mobile-devices

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using this https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula. Prety easy to integrate.