# Enable scrolling with drag-n-drop on touch devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, css

[image: table with horizontal scroll on touch devices]

Re-arranging columns and click is now working on touch devices. Now facing the issue with scrolling. I tried to resolve it with `iScroll` plugin but it didn't work. The screenshot I took from device mode of `chrome` browser.

Table columns can be added on-the-fly and so number of columns may vary.

Is there any `css` way to work scrolling properly ??? If not how do I implement it with `javascript` or `jquery` ???

**Update:**
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; is not working.

**Update 2:**
Tried with below code:

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
            $('.container-fluid').css('overflow', 'auto');            
        }
```

and this one as well:

```
 if (Modernizr.touch) {            
              //iScroll plugin                
              var myScroll = new IScroll('#tblGrid', {               
                    scrollbars: true
                });
            }
```

None of them worked.

**Update 3:**

Below is the code to enable dragging of table columns and click event:

```
var clickms = 200;
    var lastTouchDown = -1;

    function touchHandler(event) {
        var touch = event.changedTouches[0];

        var d = new Date(); var type = "";
        switch (event.type) {
            case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; lastTouchDown = d.getTime(); break;
            case "touchmove": type = "mousemove"; lastTouchDown = -1; break;
            case "touchend": if (lastTouchDown > -1 && (d.getTime() - lastTouchDown) < clickms) { lastTouchDown = -1; type = "click"; break; } type = "mouseup"; break;
            default: return;
        }

        var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
        touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
        touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
        false, false, false, 0, null);

        touch.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

function init() {
        document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
        document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
    }
$(document).ready(function () { 

init();

        var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            myScroll = new IScroll('#tblGrid', {
                mouseWheel: true,
                scrollbars: true,
                click: true,
                eventPassthrough: true,
                tap: true
            });
        }
        if (Modernizr.touch) {            
            loaded();
        }

});
```

**Update 4:**

I tried to use `iScroll 4` and scrolling now works. But when I rearrange/drag-drop columns, the scrolling also works and in that case Drag-drop does not work properly due to `touchmove` event.

And `jquery.floatThead` also stopped working which fixes the headers.

Comment: any update on scrolling on touch devices ???

Comment: @Erwinus - I've to add drag-n-drop of columns and scrolling both. When I turn on `touch` events in `chrome`, I am not able to scroll the table. Not even on mobile.

Comment: What behavior are you seeing when you try to scroll?

Comment: @E.Z.Hart - If I disable drag-n-drop scroll works fine otherwise with drag-n-drop scroll works improperly. Actually `touchmove` event causes the problem. What could be the solution for that ???

Comment: anyone has luck to get this worked ???

Comment: So, what you are seeing right now is that when you try to drag a column, the table is scrolling horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your end goal is, but let me see if I understand:

1. You want to be able to scroll your table horizontally on touch devices. This works right now.
2. You want to be able to drag and drop your columns to rearrange them. You want to do this by dragging the column headers. Right now, when you do this the `touchmove` listener is causing the whole table to scroll horizontally when you drag a column, which is a problem.

If I'm correct on the two points above, then I think what *might* fix your problem is to change `init()` so that it adds the touch listeners only to your table headers (instead of the entire document). Something like this:

```
function init() {
    $( "th" ).each(function( index ) {
        this.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
        this.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
        this.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
        this.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
    });
}
```

You would also need to apply the four event listeners to any new column headers added to the table (wherever you're currently handling you 'add column' logic).

I'm not certain this will 100% work - if you could post a repro of the problem somewhere like http://jsfiddle.net/, it might be easier to help you debug it.

Comment: the answer was helpful, but how to modify the code for only scrolling ( horizontal and vertical ) in table?