# How can i make a webview respond to a drag instead of the uiview scrolling?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have added a UIWebview to a view controller, can show a working html page that has draggable elements and a lot of javascript. The buttons work, links work, images load, javascript runs, all seems well. But the draggable elements don't drag. Instead the webview just scrolls within the view with bounces. A long tap just selects the whole web view.

How to I enable this web page to do a drag and drop instead of just scrolling it within the UIView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load your HTML in Mobile Safari, does it also scroll the view rather than dragging elements? If so, you'll need to change your JavaScript so that it's compatible with touch-based dragging.

See: [Javascript Drag and drop for touch devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices)

Comment: Good call, thanks. Both tips helped, and there really was no IOS/xcode issue to solve here.