# how to make dragable objects in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

i have some HTML elements which gives the drag front and back elements which is done by HTML, CSS and Javascript

Now am trying to make it work with touch enabled devices, but my handlers are not running on mobile devices

HTML:

CSS:

```
#progress {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 42%;
    float: left; padding-top:5px;
}
#progress #progress_box {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 14px;
    background: rgba(110,116,126,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,116,126,1) 0%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 23%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(110,116,126,1)), color-stop(23%, rgba(110,116,126,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(110,116,126,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(87,94,106,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(87,94,106,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,116,126,1) 0%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 23%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,116,126,1) 0%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 23%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(110,116,126,1) 0%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 23%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(110,116,126,1) 0%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 23%, rgba(110,116,126,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 50%, rgba(87,94,106,1) 100%);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6e747e', endColorstr='#575e6a', GradientType=0 );
    margin: 2px 0 0 5px;
    xpadding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Js :

```
  var rangesliderContainer = document.createElement('div'),
            selectionBar = document.createElement('div'),
            leftHandler = document.createElement('div'),
            rightHandler = document.createElement('div');

 rangesliderContainer.style.position = 'relative';
        rangesliderContainer.style.top = '-1em';
        rangesliderContainer.style.height = '100%';
        rangesliderContainer.id='rangeSlider';
        rangesliderContainer.setAttribute('data-myval','0');

        selectionBar.style.height = '60%';
        selectionBar.style.position = 'absolute';
        selectionBar.style.left = '0%';
        selectionBar.style.right = '0%';
        selectionBar.style.backgroundColor = '#f3752b';
        selectionBar.style.opacity = '0.8';

        leftHandler.className = 'left';
        leftHandler.style.position = 'relative';
        leftHandler.style.width = '0.3em';
        leftHandler.style.height = '100%';
        leftHandler.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        //leftHandler.style.left = '-0.5em';
        leftHandler.style.height='2em';
         leftHandler.style.backgroundColor = '#f3752b';

        rightHandler.className = 'right';
        rightHandler.style.position = 'absolute';
        rightHandler.style.width = '0.3em';
        rightHandler.style.height = '100%';
        rightHandler.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
        rightHandler.style.right = '-0.5em';
        rightHandler.style.top = '0';
        rightHandler.style.height='2em';
        rightHandler.style.backgroundColor = '#f3752b';

     rangesliderContainer.appendChild(selectionBar);
        selectionBar.appendChild(leftHandler);
        selectionBar.appendChild(rightHandler);

$('.vjs-progress-holder').append(rangesliderContainer);

 var onMouseMove = function (event) {
                var totalWidth = rangesliderContainer.offsetWidth;
                var leftEdge = rangesliderContainer.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                var position = event.pageX;

                var x = event.pageX - $('#rangeSlider').offset().left;
                //sometime x goes to negative so added Math.max
                var percent = Math.max(0, x / $('#rangeSlider').width());
               // var startTime = secondsToHms(percent * player.duration) ;
               // var endTime = secondsToHms(percent * player.duration) ;


                var currentLeft = parseFloat(selectionBar.style.left),
                    currentRight = parseFloat(selectionBar.style.right),
                    newLeft = Math.min(100, (Math.max(0, position - leftEdge) / totalWidth * 100)),
                    newRight = Math.min(100, (100 - (Math.min(totalWidth, position - leftEdge) / totalWidth * 100)));

                if (activeHandler.className === 'left') {
                    if (newLeft > 100 - currentRight) {
                        // activeHandler = activeHandler === leftHandler ? rightHandler : leftHandler;
                        // selectionBar.style.right = newRight + '%';
                        selectionBar.style.left = (100 - currentRight) + '%';
                         leftSpan.innerHTML =  startTime;
                    } else {
                        selectionBar.style.left = newLeft + '%';
                         leftSpan.innerHTML =  startTime;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (100 - newRight < currentLeft) {
                        // activeHandler = activeHandler === leftHandler ? rightHandler : leftHandler;
                        // selectionBar.style.left = newLeft + '%';
                        selectionBar.style.right = (100 - currentLeft) + '%';
                        rightSpan.innerHTML =  endTime;
                    } else {
                        selectionBar.style.right = newRight + '%';
                        rightSpan.innerHTML =  endTime;
                    }
                }
            };


var onMouseUp = function () {
                //alert('dfdff');
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);  

                 leftHandler.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
                leftHandler.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);

                 rightHandler.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
                rightHandler.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
            };

            var onMouseDown = function () {
                activeHandler = this;
               // alert('dfdff');
                document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
                document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);


                leftHandler.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
                leftHandler.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);

                 rightHandler.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
                rightHandler.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
            };


            leftHandler.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
            rightHandler.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);
```

added events for my handlers for both touch and desktop browsers, works fine with desktop but not working with touch devices

```
leftHandler.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
leftHandler.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);

rightHandler.addEventListener('touchmove', onMouseMove);
rightHandler.addEventListener('touchend', onMouseUp);
```

anyone could help me please ?

Fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxu63rfy/5/)

Answer (score 2):

The best solutions related to HTML5 on touch screens would be using [jQuery UI Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). You can find very good and working examples on this site which work well in both desktop and mobile devices.

[Draggable Objects Example](http://touchpunch.furf.com/#draggable-examples)

[Droppable Objects Example](http://touchpunch.furf.com/#droppable-examples)

**Side Note:** Please don't [reinvent the wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel). In my experiences, using powerful 3rd party libraries/components (such as jQuery which is *pure power*), the development process would be more quicker, more easier, more ... and more ... .

Answer (score 1):

In your `move` event handler, you are using `event.pageX`. Because touch devices can have multiple touch points (i.e. pinching), you need to look into the changedTouches array of the event.

Use: `event.changedTouches[0].pageX`

Comment: How to make it compatible with both touch and desktop ?

Comment: i tried `event.changedTouches[0].pageX` but doesn't work as well as https://jsfiddle.net/kxu63rfy/6/

Comment: The way you are attaching event handlers is pretty strange. You have the `touchmove` and `touchend` events attached only after a `mousedown` event. This is also attaching the event handlers multiple times (every time mouse down is triggered). A better approach would be to attach the mouse and touch events to the body, then look at the event target to see if the event is occurring on the targeted element. Another thing to consider: Windows devices use `pointer` events. You might be better off just incorporating a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186441/javascript-drag-and-drop-for-touch-devices/)

i added the codes same like in the accepted answer now i can drag the elements with the touch devices

```
function touchHandler(event) {
    var touch = event.changedTouches[0];

    var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent({
        touchstart: "mousedown",
        touchmove: "mousemove",
        touchend: "mouseup"
    }[event.type], true, true, window, 1,
        touch.screenX, touch.screenY,
        touch.clientX, touch.clientY, false,
        false, false, false, 0, null);

    touch.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
    event.preventDefault();
}

function init() {
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
    document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
}
```

Need to call init() in document ready

Only defect am getting is pinch zoom is disabled from the touch devices

Based on @Quantastical's answer i learnt that `event.changedTouches[0]` is more important for touch devices, so am giving bounty to him.