# Is it possible to detect tap and drag on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile, user-experience

As the title states, is there a way to detect if a mobile user is doing a tap and drag with javascript / jquery? Running into a user experience issue where ripple effects I have set on elements is activate while tap & dragging / browsing content on mobile devices.

Comment: Hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5186441/2401386) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [jQuery touch punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/) for that.

You have great documentation and lots of events you can hook into for all sorts of tasks.

You can do things like Drag/Drop, Resize and more..

Comment: Thank you, will take a look and see if it has what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JQuery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com). It has [tap](https://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/) and [swipe](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipe/) events.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. I take it jquery mobile works fine while using standard jquery?

Comment: Yes it is, take a look and let me know :)

Comment: Yes, it actually requires it.