# AngularJS: drag and drop directives work on navigator but they dont work on my touch devices

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I developed drag and drop directives in angularJS and it's working on my navigator (computer) but it didn't work in my touch devices. Is there something I should do to adapt my code to work on my touch devices? or should I change the code in the directives ? Here you find a snippet of my code

```js
module.exports = angular
  .module('app.dashboard.controller', ['ngTouch'])
  .controller('appDashboard', appDashboard)
  .directive('draggable', draggable)
  .directive('droppable', droppable);
function droppable() {
        return {
            scope: {
            drop: '&',
            bin: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            // again we need the native object
            var el = element[0];
      
            el.addEventListener(
                'dragover',
                function(e) {
                    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
                    // allows us to drop
                    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                    this.classList.add('over');
                    return false;
                },
                false
            );
      
            el.addEventListener(
                'dragenter',
                function(e) {
                    this.classList.add('over');
                    return false;
                },
                false
            );
      
            el.addEventListener(
                'dragleave',
                function(e) {
                    this.classList.remove('over');
                    return false;
                },
                false
            );
      
            el.addEventListener(
                'drop',
                function(e) {
                    // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
                    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
          
                    this.classList.remove('over');
          
                    var binId = this.id;
                    var item = document.getElementById(e.dataTransfer.getData('Text')).cloneNode(true);
                    item.classList.remove('drag');
                    this.appendChild(item);
                    // call the passed drop function
                    scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                        var fn = scope.drop();
                        if ('undefined' !== typeof fn) {            
                            fn(item.id, binId);
                        }
                    });
          
                    return false;
                },
                false
            );
        }
        }
    }
function draggable() {
    return {
      scope: {
        drag: '&' // parent
      },
      link: function(scope, element) {
    // this gives us the native JS object
        var el = element[0];
    
        el.draggable = true;
    
        el.addEventListener(
          'dragstart',
          function(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
            this.classList.add('drag');
            return false;
          },
          false
        );
    
      el.addEventListener(
        'dragend',
        function(e) {
          this.classList.remove('drag');
          return false;
        },
        false
      );
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6362527/6554634 check here

Comment: where should I call the init() function in my code ? I don't have document.ready in my code

Comment: Why can't you write it in a js file and load?

Comment: Sorry I am a  newbie in angularJS so any help  is appreciated  :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
el.addEventListener(
            'touchend',
            function(e) {
                e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move';
                // allows us to drop
                if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
                this.classList.add('over');
                return false;
            },
            false
        )
```

You have to use the touchstart,touchmove and touchend event and control the positions or you can use Jquery UI library with touch Punch Library. Here is the link [implementing Drag and Drop for touch Devices](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/touch-friendly-drag-and-drop)

Comment: You need to get hold of the element throught JQuery lite .Pass class name in attribute and access through isolated scope

var elem =$(class-name); // class name is the property passed in isolated scope
in link function and add the attach draggable events to it 
elem.draggable();

Link - https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

If you add the touchPunch library it will work , no need to add additional code but it wont work in some devices, better go with hammer JS/ Kinetic JS

Comment: Is there any way to not pass by jquery ?

Comment: Jquery UI uses Jquery therefore just leverage JQuery