# Drag and drop html elements in tabled devices

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, drag-and-drop

I have web site that has number of visual items. I need to drag and drop it (change order).

I am using next approach for [drag and drop in knockout](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html).

It works cool for desktop, but I want to use this on tabled devices too.

Could any body to suggest me anything that will work on tabled devices too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery UI, there's a "punch" event that would solve problem.
A similar question was asked here:
[HTML Drag And Drop On Mobile Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172100/html-drag-and-drop-on-mobile-devices)