# how to catch an event on mobile event "dragenter"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to catch an event when the item being dragged is above the target on mobile devices, it is supported by default on the desktop, how do I do this on mobile?

Comment: Do you use any frameworks?

Comment: This answer will most likely help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736245/533976

Comment: yes, i use https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/